# Modal body content not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup that displays both the header and the footer but does not display the body content.
I know this might be redundant but most solutions were either problems with css or using the 'hide' attribute on the div class which I have not used. Both Bootstrap and JavaScript are linked correctly on the layout file.
Here's a code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<a class="primary-btn text-uppercase" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerForTraining" href="#registerForTraining">Register for Training</a>&nbsp;
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="registerForTraining" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerForTrainingTitle"
                    aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="registerForTrainingLongTitle">Register for Training</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#registerForTraining').modal('show')</script>
```

I am using Flask hence if I need to add anything to my routes I'd want to know as well.
Kindly help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Supply codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Here's the link but funny enough on the fiddle the content is displayed. https://jsfiddle.net/7p30w8qg/ @AdamOrlov

Comment: Have you tried to remove `href` from `a` ? Can you add a full (including js files imported) example?

Comment: The href doesn't affect anything. And about the files, I'm not sure I can do that. @MatteoGaggiano

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason is the  `aria-hidden="true"`, try removing the attribute or setting it to `false`.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="registerForTraining" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerForTrainingTitle"
                    aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
```